Error when using hub.KerasLayer using tf.keras.sequential to make deep learning model
# Create a function which builds a Keras model

def create_model(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, output_shape=OUTPUT_SHAPE, model_url=MODEL_URL):
  print("Building model with:", MODEL_URL)

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(MODEL_URL), # Layer 1 (input layer)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=OUTPUT_SHAPE, 
                          activation="softmax") # Layer 2 (output layer)
  ])


  # Compile the model
  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), # Our model wants to reduce this (how wrong its guesses are)
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), # A friend telling our model how to improve its guesses
      metrics=["accuracy"] # We'd like this to go up
  )

  # Build the model
  model.build(INPUT_SHAPE) # Let the model know what kind of inputs it'll be getting
  
  return model

I have the function just above and when i run the other program like bellow
model = create_model()
model.summary()

it create some error
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. 
Received: layer=<Dense name=dense_18, built=False> of type <class 'keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense'>.

What did i got wrong?
